# What is the difference between IRS on SOFR and OIS on SOFR?

Tags: ois-swaps

Consider the floating leg of an IRS based on SOFR.

Now consider the floating leg of an overnight indexed swap based on SOFR.

I understand that the former will pay the actual SOFR rate on the fixing date, wheres the latter is an average of the daily rates.

However, say I want to calculate the PV of my floating legs. Are both legs valued equally? That is, consider the payment that occurs at time $T_2$ and fixes from $T_1$. Is the projected discounted value of this payment equal on both legs, computed from the forward SOFR rates?

And if not, what is the difference?

Comment: That is not true. SOFR IRS and SOFR OIS are the same. IRS and OIS used to represent two quite different swaps when LIBOR was around. They generally provided a difference between these two indexes. Without LIBOR I generally use the terms OIS and IRS interchangably and dont even use OIS much for currencies where the only index is an RFR. For IBOR based currencies, eg EUR, SEK, NOK, etc. OIS and IRS can still separate our these indexes.